# Issue creating stream definitions via rest interface

Tags: spring-xd

I want to make sure I am on the right track with this.

I am getting the following response when attempting to create my stream:

> 015-11-23T08:59:12-0800 1.3.0.RELEASE ERROR qtp1260026681-23 rest.RestControllerAdvice - Caught exception while handling a request
>   org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:204) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]

Here is my sample code:

```
HttpEntity<String> requestEntity;
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity;

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
map.add("name", "testStream");
map.add("definition", "file | log");
map.add("deploy", "true");

requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap>(map, headers);

String url = "http://localhost:9393/streams/definitions"

try
{
    responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
    body = responseEntity.getBody();
    statusCode = responseEntity.getStatusCode();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    String test = e.getMessage();
}
```

Here is the code that returns the: exception is java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
*
^

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

def streamName = "TEST";

def url= "http://localhost:9393/streams/definitions";

String definition = "dod-file-source --dir='zxcv' --dir='([^\s]+(\.(?i)(tar))$)' | transform --script=dod.file.transform.groovy --variables='hotfolderId=1' > queue:StorageStream";

MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>()
map.add("name", streamName)
map.add("definition", definition)
map.add("deploy", 'true')

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
String body = responseEntity.getBody();
HttpStatus statusCode = responseEntity.getStatusCode();
```

That is a custom source module dod-file-source but it just adds a few additional features to the file source module

Comment: oops - i think I found the issue I did not properly set the right property - let me get back to you on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran (a slightly modified version of) your code and had no problems...

```
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> requestEntity;
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity;

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
map.add("name", "testStream");
map.add("definition", "time | log");
map.add("deploy", "true");

requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

String url = "http://localhost:9393/streams/definitions";

try
{
    responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
    String body = responseEntity.getBody();
    HttpStatus statusCode = responseEntity.getStatusCode();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}


2015-11-23T13:00:44-0500 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO task-scheduler-1 sink.testStream - 2015-11-23 13:00:44
2015-11-23T13:00:45-0500 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO task-scheduler-1 sink.testStream - 2015-11-23 13:00:45
2015-11-23T13:00:46-0500 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO task-scheduler-1 sink.testStream - 2015-11-23 13:00:46
2015-11-23T13:00:47-0500 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO task-scheduler-1 sink.testStream - 2015-11-23 13:00:47
```

Comment: Thanks Gary - I was sending in the incorrect url for the POST

Comment: Actually I do have a follow-on question/issue: when I attempt to pass into the definition something like this --pattern='([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(tar))$)' I am getting an error in the bean creation for a custom filter I have setup CustomCompositeFileListFilter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0

Comment: I do not encounter this when creating the definition via the xd-shell

Comment: Can you show the actual code you are using to generate the request? (It's easier to read if you edit the question rather than adding it as a comment).

Comment: Please disregard this follow-on question. I did not properly build up the stream definition correctly... Thanks for the support!